# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when adding UINavigationController in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have inherited a large code that keeps crashing during `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` on `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]` with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address...), so I have no useful information on console. Through elimination I have separated a simple example below that will crash when adding navigationController view onto the baseVC.view. Can anybody please help and explain why is it crashing and how to fix it?

```
@interface ViewController () <UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *baseVC;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *customNC;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.baseVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    CGSize size = self.view.bounds.size;
    self.baseVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height );

    [self.view addSubview:self.baseVC.view];

    self.customNC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.baseVC];
    [self addChildViewController:self.customNC];
    [self.customNC setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    self.customNC.delegate = self;

    self.customNC.view.frame = self.baseVC.view.frame;
    [self.baseVC.view addSubview:self.customNC.view];
}

@end
```

The actual code is I have is more complex, but the behaviour of this sample is the same. Thank you.

Edit:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[RootVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootVC" bundle:nil];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.customNC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.baseVC];
[self.baseVC.view addSubview:self.customNC.view];
```

The problem is in this code lines. So, self.baseVC.view is in self.customNC.view, and vice versa. It causes the crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

This exception occurs when you have problem with memory of the app probably something is already released and you try to use it. To debug this use iOS instruments.

Try to add this line to if you do not have this didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
[self.window addSubview:[self.navigationController view]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: I have `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the actual app. In the example above I just used the SingleView app template and added the above few lines of code in ViewController.m as you see it.

Comment: Try to run you're app in instruments iOS and see history of this problem. You will be able to see all memory references.

Comment: I'll try, but I am sure the last line in the sample above is causing the crash. If I comment `[self.baseVC.view addSubview:self.customNC.view];` out and add `NSLog(@"%@ %@", self.customNC, self.baseVC);` on the end, I see both baseVC and customNC exist in memory.

Comment: show you're didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method pls

Comment: Added the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Comment: is that ARC or not-ARC proect?

Comment: ARC is enabled. As mentioned, if you create new blank project in latest Xcode based on Single View App template and paste the code above into viewDidLoad of the ViewController.m (no need for didFinishLaunchingWithOptions code as it will use storyboard), you will replicate the crash.

Comment: i edit answer lets try consider this flow as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170921/exc-bad-access-when-adding-uinavigationcontroller-to-window

Comment: I see where you're heading, but in my case I have some custom ViewController (RootVC) set as the rootViewController of the window object and then in the viewDidLoad code of this VC I am adding a BaseVC and then adding Navigation Controller onto this BaseVC. So the navigation controller is not the rootViewcontroller of the app, it is added onto some viewcontrollers. Don't ask me why is this, but the whole setup is very complex (means not easy to change) and it was actually working fine until few weeks back.